# Unable to get Onedrive shared file permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to retrieve OneDrive personal shared file permission using following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/permissions
```

But in response I am receiving following:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('myemail%40yahoo.com')/drive/items('fileid')/permissions",
    "value": []
}
```

Instead of something as following mentioned on [Microsoft OneDrive Graph API documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_permissions):

```json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "roles": ["write"],
      "grantedTo": {
        "user": {
          "id": "5D33DD65C6932946",
          "displayName": "John Doe"
        }
      },
      "inheritedFrom": {
        "driveId": "1234567890ABD",
        "id": "1234567890ABC!123",
        "path": "/drive/root:/Documents" }
    }                
  ]
}
```

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior for files in a personal OneDrive that have not been shared with anyone. The `Owner` permission for personal OneDrive is implied (the owner of the drive is the owner of every file within that drive) so it would only show `Read` and `Write` permissions (if any exist).